# Setting microphone input volume using the command line?

Tags: command-line, pulseaudio

I have a USB mic I keep plugging into my laptop dock. When I drop into the dock I'd like the mic setup as my current audio input automatically. I do have a "I'm docked" script I run which sets xrandr/etc items, I'd just need some method perform the action of:

gnome-volume-control, input tab, choose mic

but from the cmd line/script.

Any hints on how I can automate/script this?

Answer (score 14):

If you are using ALSA, amixer can be helpful for your script programming.

When dropping the `amixer --help` command in a terminal you will see something like this:

[image]

Depending on your soundcard, levels may be different than mine, but you can use `alsamixer` in the terminal in order to check which levels and which features in your sound card you can call in a command to set the volume as you wish.

[image]

In my example, with my principal sound card (I have 2: the embedded and a PCI audio card), levels are from 0 to 100, this way I can change the volume of a desired input/output in my soundcard by dropping in a terminal the next command:

```
amixer -c 0 set Front 50DB 
amixer -c 0 set Front 64DB
```

In the first command, the result will set the Front panel output to 78% level and the second one will set the Front panel output to 100% level.

In order to gather information related to your mixer controls, drop the `amixer` command with no parameters and you will get a list. Or indicate which audio device you wish to see a list of controls with `amixer -c X` (where "X" is the number of your audio device).

BTW: Remember that DB values are calculated logarithmically and not linearly.

Comment: From where can I install the amixer? sudo apt-get install amixer on ubuntu 13.04 does not do the trick

Comment: You may need to install (or reinstall if needed) `alsa-lib` and/or `alsa-utils` by dropping in a terminal `sudo apt-get install alsa-utils --reinstall` Please note that the `--reinstall` is only needed if you wish to reinstall. Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

I have found a better answer by looking in the docs (probably is a recent addition to pacmd...)

Use `pacmd list-sources` to see the different input devices, the one with the `*   index: ...` is the one active.

You can then use `pacmd set-source-volume <index> <volume>` to set the volume, In my case using `50%` as an arguments was failing, so I just tried different numbers until it showed as 50% in the UI.

For me `pacmd set-source-volume 1 30000` was the line that worked

Cheers!

Comment: FWIW, the audio level as a number is visible in `pacmd list-sources`. So to simplify the "finding the right number" stage, you can configure the audio level with a software like pavucontrol and then look at the number in `pacmd list-sources`.

Answer (score 7):

Possibly `pacmd set-default-source` works if you are using pulseaudio, for example:

```
pacmd set-default-source alsa_input.usb-046d_0819_9F13DC90-02-U0x46d0x819.analog-mono
```

Find the source name using the command: `pacmd list-sources`.

Comment: Linux Mint 18.1, here. My "Sound" settings would not change input device from Acer's built-in mic, but using this command finally worked: `pacmd set-default-source "alsa_input.usb-Samson_Technologies_Samson_Meteor_Mic-00.analog-stereo"`

Answer (score 0):

In relation to #4, I wrote a program that finds the index, and then sets the level to 250000:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

void exec(string str) {
const char *command = str.c_str();
system(command);
}


int main() {

exec("pacmd list-sources | grep \"*\" > tmp");
fstream file ("tmp");
string output;
if (file.is_open() && !file.eof()) {
getline(file, output, '\n');
}
file.close();

char id;

id = output.back();

exec("rm tmp");

string command = (string) "pacmd set-source-volume " + id + " 250000";

exec(command);

return 0;
}
```