# "amixer set master mute" not working with external USB speakers

Tags: sound

I'm trying to get the command "amixer set master mute" to work when the active sound output is an external USB speaker, but it doesn't work. It only seems to work if the output is the built-in speaker or the headphone out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next was previously posted in this answer: [Setting microphone input volume using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27021/setting-audio-input-via-cmd-line/27032#27032)

Taking in consideration what I mention over here, in your case it would be something like:

```
amixer -c 0 set Master 0DB
```

But you should perform tests in order to check it.

I hope this is helpful for you.

> If you are using ALSA, amixer can be helpful for your script
>   programming.
>
> When dropping the `amixer --help` command in a terminal you will see
>   something like this:
>
> [image]
>
> Depending on your soundcard, levels may be different than mine, but
>   you can use `alsamixer` in the terminal in order to check which levels
>   and which features in your sound card you can call in a command to set
>   the volume as you wish.
>
> [image]
>
> In my example, with my principal sound card (I have 2: the embedded
>   and a PCI audio card), levels are from 0 to 100, this way I can change
>   the volume of a desired input/output in my soundcard by dropping in a
>   terminal the next command:
>
> ```
> amixer -c 0 set Front 50DB 
> amixer -c 0 set Front 64DB
> ```
>
> In the first command, the result will set the Front panel output to
>   78% level and the second one will set the Front panel output to 100%
>   level.
>
> In order to gather information related to your mixer controls, drop
>   the `amixer` command with no parameters and you will get a list. Or
>   indicate which audio device you wish to see a list of controls with
>   `amixer -c X` (where "X" is the number of your audio device).
>
> BTW: Remember that DB values are calculated logarithmically and not
>   linearly.

Comment: Tested by me: it works. With the amixer -c 0 set Master 0DB, Good luck!