# Terminal commands for volume

Tags: command-line

I have a very simple question: What is the terminal command for changing the volume? I ask because I want to set a keyboard shortcut via the keyboard settings and I need the terminal command for it.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to open whole audio mixer in terminal you can user `alsamixer`.
Then you'll get screen with some colored sliders. You can adjust their values with arrows on your keyboard. It looks like this: 
[image]

But if you want to change volume with single command, you can use:

- `amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+` - This will increase you master
  volume by 5%.
- `amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-` - This will decrease volume by 5%
- `amixer -D pulse sset Master 50%` - And this will set volume to 50%

You can find topic simmilar to yours here if you want to get more information: [Terminal command to set audio volume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97936/terminal-command-to-set-audio-volume)

I think it's pretty easy and it works for me. I hope this helped you :)