# Command line program to show speaker monitor details

Tags: sound

Is there a command line program (available in Ubuntu) to display details (e.g. alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor) of the speaker monitor? I want to be able to use these details to provide a -f parameter when using ffmpeg to capture sound played through the speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're example mentions ALSA, it could be `amixer` that you're looking for (also see `alsamixer` but it uses ncurses based interface)...

Type in terminal for a complete list of simple mixer controls with their contents:

```
amixer  scontents
```

or simply,

```
amixer
```

Here is a [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27021/setting-audio-input-via-cmd-line/27032#27032) for example.

`amixer` output example:

[image: amixer-image]

`alsamixer` ncurses interface:

[image: alsamixer-image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want to do with it, but

```
pactl list
```

will print out the details of modules/sinks/sources/clients, etc. If you need only the monitor source use something like

```
pactl list sources
```

or

```
pactl list short sources
```

Then filter out the output with sed/awk as you want. (If you provide exactly which details you want I can help filtering out, but I guess you know how to do that.)